# Proving that $||v - \text{proj}_F^\perp (v)|| \le ||v - u||,\forall u \in F $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I'm having some trouble proving the following proposition:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product real vector space: For each $v\in V$ it's orthogonal projection over $F \le V$ (denoted by: $\text{proj}_F^\perp 
> (v)$) is the closest vector of $F$ to $v$, in other words: $$||v - \text{proj}_F^\perp 
> (v)|| \le ||v - u||,\forall u \in F $$

I tried a direct proof, I tried a proof by contradiction, but I wan's able to prove this proposition. How can this proof be done?

Comment: How do you define $\operatorname{proj}_F^\perp$?

Comment: Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product real vector space, $F \le V$ and $v \in V$. Because $V = F \oplus F^\perp$, then $\exists f \in F, f' \in F^\perp: v = f + f'$. $\text{proj}^\perp _F (v) = f$ and  $\text{proj}^\perp _{F^\perp} (v) = f'$. This is the deffinition. @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v\in V$, and if $f\in F$ and $f'\in F^\perp$ are such that $v=f+f'$, then $f=\operatorname{proj}F^\perp(v)$ and, for any $u\in F$,\begin{align}\|v-u\|^2&=\bigl\|(v-f)+(f-u)\bigr\|^2\\&=\|v-f\|^2+\|f-u\|^2\text{ (because $f-u\in F$ and $v-f\in F^\perp$)}\\&\geqslant\|v-f\|^2.\end{align}